# Handling special characters ñ in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, character, globalization

I have a Web application using asp.net MVC (c#). When generate a View from a controller, characters like ñ appears without any problems. But when run debugger mode the page doesn't display this characters and show me this: CompaÃ±Ã­a > Crear

Appreciate any help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a debugger problem. There's nothing special about "ñ". It's a normal Unicode string.